# Initialization webservice in angularJS for all routes

Tags: angularjs, web-services, routes

I need to get some information from a webservice before anything is loaded, for all routes. In fact, that webservice is in charge of getting the proper "theme", so it must be known before anything loads.

Until now i solved this kind of issues with the "resolve" property of each route. I don't know if this would be enough tough.

Anyway, adding that resolve condition manually to all routes doesn't sound good to me. Is there a ellegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an ng-init in your AppCtrl that you load in your index.html (where you have your main ng-view). Consequently, you could store the state/result in the rootScope or in another way in which it is accesible to all your controllers.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="callWebservice()">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```